# Subset df based on value in a column and retrieve 30 days before and after a given date

Tags: r

I've got a data frame which consists of columns containing a date, Id and a dummy variable (similar to the set below).

I would like to subtract the rows of ID '56' where the date is 2014-12-03 + 30 days before and after the given date. And the same for ID '1998'.

```
      date     Dummy  ID
1   2014-12-01  1932     56
2   2014-12-02  1828     201
3   2014-12-03  2349     56
4   2014-12-04  8192     100
5   2014-12-05  3188     56
6   2014-12-06  3277     1998

v1 = c(56, 1998)
v2 = c(2014-12-03, 2014-12-06)
```

Ending up with something like below

```
      date     Dummy  ID
1   2014-12-01  1932     56
3   2014-12-03  2349     56
5   2014-12-05  3188     56
6   2014-12-06  3277     1998
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One basic option is that you make a data frame out of your conditions, join it to the initial one by `ID` and then filter:

```
library(dplyr)

matchdf <- data.frame(ID = c(56, 1998),
                      conditions = c("2014-12-03", "2014-12-06"))

df %>%
  left_join(matchdf, by = "ID") %>%
  mutate_at(vars(date, conditions), list(~ as.Date)) %>%
  filter(date >= conditions - 30 & date <= conditions + 30) %>%
  select(-conditions)
```

Output:

```
        date Dummy   ID
1 2014-12-01  1932   56
2 2014-12-03  2349   56
3 2014-12-05  3188   56
4 2014-12-06  3277 1998
```

Answer (score 3):

```
library(data.table)
library(dplyr)

data <- data.table(
  date = seq(as.Date("2014/12/1"), as.Date("2014/12/6"), "days"),
  Dummy = c(1932, 1828, 2349, 8192, 3188, 3277),
  ID = c(56, 201, 56, 100, 56, 1998)
  )


given_date <- as.Date("2014/12/3")

data %>% 
  filter(between(date, given_date - 30, given_date + 30), ID == 56 | ID == 1998)
```

Output:

```
        date Dummy   ID
1 2014-12-01  1932   56
2 2014-12-03  2349   56
3 2014-12-05  3188   56
4 2014-12-06  3277 1998
```